# How to make database call without losing this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j

Because database is a separate object in itself, calling it I lose `this`

```
var neo4j = require('neo4j');
var db = new neo4j.GraphDatabase('http://localhost:7474');

function MyObject(id){this.id = id}
MyObject.prototype.myQuery = function(){
    db.query('Some Query',{args:params},function(callback){
        //this in here is some neo4j db related object.
        //instead of MyObject
        console.log(this.id); //undefined
    });
}
myObject = new MyObject(9);
myObject.myQuery(); //undefined
```

Any workaround to make the database call and still have my `this` refer to the original intended object from inside the db's callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from saving it to a variable, you can also bind `this` to a function as shown here:

```
MyObject.prototype.myQuery = function(){
    db.query('Some Query',{args:params},function(callback){
        //this in here is some neo4j db related object.
        //instead of MyObject
        console.log(this.id); //undefined
    }.bind(this));
}
```

... or use arrow functions from ES6, even though it's not yet an option...

Answer (score 3):

Cache it before the call :

```
MyObject.prototype.myQuery = function(){
    var self = this;
    db.query('QUERY',{args:params},function(callback){
        //If you use self here, it will work.
        console.log(self.id);
    });
}
```

Comment: May the downvoter explain what is wrong? Would be useful for everyone.

Comment: Other common names for saving this are `_this` and `that`.

Answer (score 0):

You can save `this` before you call the `db.query` method, like so:

```
MyObject.prototype.myQuery = function(){
  var thisQuery = this;
  db.query('QUERY',{args:params},function(callback){
    // Now you can use thisQuery to refer to your query object
  }
}
```